# iOS Bluetooth not working from custom keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, custom-keyboard

I am trying to create a custom keyboard extension through an iOS app. What I want to do is open the custom keyboard extension outside of my container app and establish a connection with my BLE device.

I can successfully make this work in the container app (i.e. connect to device and receive the data I want). However, when I launch what is essentially the same code in the KeyboardViewController.Swift, I get the error:

```
[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
central.state is unsupported.
```

This error comes from this code:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state{
    case .unknown:
        print("central.state is unknown.")
    case .resetting:
        print("central.state is resetting.")
    case .unsupported:
        print("central.state is unsupported.")
    case .unauthorized:
        print("central.state is unauthorized.")
    case .poweredOff:
        print("central.state is poweredoff.")
    case .poweredOn:
        print("central.state is poweredOn.")
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
    }
}
```

My question is: Can a keyboard extension access Bluetooth capabilities? Does anyone have a link to more information on how to successfully integrate CoreBluetooth in a KeyboardViewController?

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you provide documentation for this? I know apps exist that work the way I want mine to.

Comment: Note that app review requires that your keyboard extension still function if open access is not granted